# How to convert date to lower case within a bash script without declaring variable?

Tags: bash, lowercase

I am trying to convert the date to all lower case in a bash script command.
However, I am trying not to first declare a variable and then converting.

I tried

```
rclone sync /home/homeassistant GoogleDrive:/homeassistant_$(date +%A)|tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' -vv --exclude=/config/secrets.yaml --exclude=/config/home-assistant_v2.db --delete-excluded
```

but that leads to the excludes to be ignored (essentially everything after to conversion is cut off).
Does anybody know a simple fix for this? Unfortunately the `date` only supports conversion to upper case using `^` but not to lower case.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: `d="$(rclone sync /home/homeassistant GoogleDrive:/homeassistant_$(date +%A)"` saving the result to `d` (or whatever name you want) and then for lowercase it's simply `"${d,,}"` in bash using the lowercase parameter expansion.

Comment: `$(cmd)|cmd2` will not cause cmd to pipe through cmd2. Use `$(cmd|cmd2)` for that

Comment: Or if it is just the date you want, then `d="$(date +%A)"` and `"${d,,}"`. Note, the lowercase parameter expansion is a *bashism* (as is uppercase `"${d^^}"`) - they are only available in bash, not POSIX or other shells.

Comment: So simple `$(cmd|cmd2)`
I could have sworn I tried that. But must have made a mistake.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Both of these declare a variable, which the question is explicitly against

Comment: You may want to say: `rclone sync /home/homeassistant GoogleDrive:/homeassistant_$(date +%A | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') -vv --exclude=/config/secrets.yaml --exclude=/config/home -assistant_v2.db --delete-excluded`.

Comment: Just being curious: What do you dislike when it comes to the use of variables?

Comment: I don't generally dislike them and was thinking of piping it through, but in this particular case I just wanted to have a command without variable. The more integrated approach made it a bit "cleaner" for me.